# How can I run Kotlin suspend fun on @ReactMethod (ReactNative)

Tags: react-native, kotlin, grpc, kotlin-coroutines

I need to implement a custom **gRPC** on **Kotlin native side**.
`@ReactMethod` can't be `suspend func`.
How can I run it?

```
@ReactMethod
fun connect(ipAddress: String, port: Int) {
    try {
        channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(ipAddress, port).usePlaintext().build()

        var guidKey = Metadata.Key.of("GUID", Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER)
        metadata.put(guidKey, GUID)

        val stub = DBServiceGrpcKt.DBServiceCoroutineStub(channel!!)

        var request = GrpcDBService.SignInRequest.newBuilder()
            .setUserName("user")
            .setPassword("11111")
            .build()

        try {
            //******* this part *****
            suspend fun coroutine() {
                var response = stub.trySignIn(request,metadata)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d("grpcConnect", e.localizedMessage)
        }
    } catch (e: Error) {
        Log.d("grpcConnect ", e.localizedMessage)
    }
    finally {
        channel?.shutdown()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a coroutine, for example, define a scope (somewhere in your class) and use it with launch:

```
myPluginScope.launch {
   val response = stub.trySignIn(request,metadata)
   // Return, the result
}
```

Creating the scope is easy, the tricky part is to find where to cancel it. Check the documentation on React native modules to find a good place to call `cancel` on your scope:

```
val myPluginScope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob() + Dispatchers.Main.immediate)
```

Now, is important to decide whether the `connect` function should behave as an asynchronous function or not. For example, if the sign in operation takes time or uses the network, `connect` should probably return the result through a `Promise` or `Callback`, so the Javascript side is not blocked:

```
@ReactMethod
fun connect(ipAddress: String, port: Int, promise: Promise) {
    myPluginScope.launch {
        try {
            // Make the sign in happen in a separate thread:
            val response = withContext(context = Dispatchers.IO) {
                stub.trySignIn(request, metadata)
            }
            // Resolve the promise in the calling thread (The UI thread)
            promise.resolve(response.hypotheticalCode)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            promise.reject("Sign in error!", e)
        }
    }
}
```

See:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android#promises
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/async-programming.html#coroutines